# CORS issue when using $http.post() in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm creating a test app for working with IdentityServer 3 and i'm using AngularJs, Angular Ui Router and oauth-ng library for creating this. My app needs to work with OpenID connect Authorization Code Flow in the Client side. So i have made quite small changes to the oauth-ng library. I am using oauth-ng lib to retrieve the authorization code from the IdentityServer3 and i'm using $http.post() to send that code to the token-endpoint and get the access_token.

The following is my code..

**JavaScript**

```
.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $location) {

        var getParamsFromUrl = function(url) {
            var splitted = url.split('?');
            splitted = splitted[1].split('&');
            var params = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
                var param  = splitted[i].split('=');
                var key    = param[0];
                var value  = param[1];
                params[key] = value
            }
            return params;
        };

        var getToken = function (url, data) {
            return $http.post(url, data);
        };



        if($location.absUrl().split('?')[1]) {
            $scope.params = getParamsFromUrl($location.absUrl());

            var tokenData = {};
            tokenData.grant_type = 'authorization_code';
            tokenData.code = $scope.params.code;
            tokenData.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/login.html';

            var tokenEndpoint = 'https://localhost:44333/core/connect/token';

            getToken(tokenEndpoint, tokenData)
                .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(headers);
                    console.log(config);
                });

        }
    });
```

The authorization code is successfully retrieved and when i try to connect to the token endpoint it throws the following error on the browser.

> OPTIONS https://localhost:44333/core/connect/token b @
>   angular.min.js:87n @ angular.min.js:82$get.f @
>   angular.min.js:80(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:112$get.n.$eval
>   @ angular.min.js:126$get.n.$digest @ angular.min.js:123$get.n.$apply @
>   angular.min.js:126(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:17e @
>   angular.min.js:36d @ angular.min.js:17uc @ angular.min.js:18Jd @
>   angular.min.js:17(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min.js:250n.Callbacks.j @
>   jquery.min.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready
>   @ jquery.min.js:2I @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:44333/core/connect/token.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Then i tried with configuring the $httpProvider in app config with this line of code.. My config looks like this.

```
.config(function ($locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true; // <= Added this
    });
```

Still get the same issue. How can i fix this issue from the Client side? can i fix this from client side?

Comment: 99% being a server-side configuration. I ran into this several times and always was the server that is not configured, try to check server-side at first.

Comment: CORS is a server side issue.try http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: OK now I think is 100% @charlietfl

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys.. I'll have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service you are requesting is not allowing CORS (no Access-Control are sent as part of the response). You would need to include the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * as part of the response.

See this : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Also refer this: http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the code grant flow is for server-side applications. you should only use the code grant if you can keep the client secret "secret"!

Is their a reason to not use the implicit flow? This way you would get the token fight in the redirect, instead of the token.

On this page are the flows explained. http://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect